# Rspec: how to spec request.env in a helper spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, request, user-agent, specifications

In my helper module, I have:

```
def abc(url)
  ...
  if request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
    do something
  end
end
```

In my spec file, I have:

```
  describe "#abc" do      
before(:each) do
  @meth = :abc

  helper.request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = "..."
end
it "should return the webstart jnlp file" do
  @obj.send(@meth, "some_url").should ....
end
end
```

When I run the spec I have this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `request' for <ObjectWithDocHelperMixedIn:0x00000103b5a7d0>
```

How do I stub for request.env['...'] in my specs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

If you're using [rspec-rails](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails), you might be able to use `controller.request` in your helper tests.

Answer (score 11):

Well, you've almost nothing to do:

```
before(:each) do
  @meth = :abc

  request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = "..."
end
```

I just gave this another try and this passes:

```
#in helper
def foo
  request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
end

#spec
it "foo" do
  helper.request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = 'foo'
  expect(helper.foo).to eq 'foo'
end
```

Comment: I do this in controller specs though... never tried in helper specs.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Yeah I tried that before too but it didn't work in helper specs (at least in my case).

Comment: one easy workaround would be to extract condition to methods in your helper and stub those methods

Answer (score 5):

You can override user-agent set in the request env by doing the following.

```
before(:each) do
  @meth = :abc
  helper.request.user_agent = 'something else'
end
```

Then, in your spec:

```
it "does stuff" do
  expect(helper.send(@meth, "some_url")).to # ...
end
```

Answer (score 4):

for those who use request specs instead of controller specs and want to set `request.env` can do it like this:

```
Rails.application.env_config["whatever"] = "whatever"
```

this will make `request.env["whatever"]` available in your controllers with value you gave it in your specs.

Comment: Unfortunately this persists after the individual test, so it causes every other request after this one to be made with the same env, which can cause unexpected differences in other suites that otherwise would be well isolated. Is there a way to stub this so RSpec replaces it automatically, like allow()?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`stub(request).env { {"HTTP_USER_AGENT" => "Some String"} }`