# Rspec for Detecting devises

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, user-agent

This is my task

1) Create a new route localhost:3000/device

2) Consider if this url is hit from the mobile phones or desktop browsers, then

3) Track the system/device (iOS, android, web) from which the URL is hit

4) Based on the device from which the request has come, we need to redirect to some other URL (e.g., iOS ——> “iOS app store”, android ——> “Android play store”, web ——> “google page”)

5) Find what are the different approaches that are available to track the system from which the request has come and what would be the best one to implement and why?

Here I found a solution, but in rspec it causes error.

This is my route

```
get :devise, to: 'topics#devise'
```

And this is my controller

```
class TopicsController < ApplicationController
  def devise
    if request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].downcase.match(/mac/i)
      redirect_to 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/id375380948?mt=8'
    elsif request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].downcase.match(/windows/i)
      redirect_to 'https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/windows'
    elsif request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].downcase.match(/android/i)
      redirect_to 'https://play.google.com/store?hl=en'
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

When I hit url `lvh.me:3000/devise` it redirects to the respective app store.

This is my controller spec

```
context 'devise' do
  it 'should detect the device' do
    get :devise
    response.should redirect_to '/https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/windows'
  end 
end
```

and this caused the error:

> Expected response to be a redirect to http://test.host/https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/windows but was a redirect to http://test.host/.
>   
>  Expected "http://test.host/https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/windows" to be === "http://test.host/".

If I did it in a wrong way, tell some suggestion for doing rspec

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132363/rspec-how-to-spec-request-env-in-a-helper-spec, it should help

Comment: Thanks @vasilisa. Got some idea on it.

Comment: This code could really be improved by using a [case statement](https://www.rubyguides.com/2015/10/ruby-case/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your rails version is not too ancient in controller you can use `request.user_agent` (it will look into env anyway, but this makes code cleaner)

Browsers pass user agent in header `User-agent` (which in turn ends up in rack env), so you need to simulate this in your tests.

For testing this I'd recommend using request  specs instead of controller ones (which are deprecated in rails 5):

```
 RSpec.describe 'Topics...', type: :request do
   it "redirects for ios" do
     get '/your/topcis/path/here', headers: { 'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'iPhone' }
     expect(response).to redirect_to(/\.apple\.com/)
   end
 end
```

(above uses rails 5, for older rails headers will be just hash, not a keyword argument)

Also you can write your method with `case` statement:

```
def devise
  redirect_to case request.user_agent.downcase
              when /mac/i     then 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/id375380948?mt=8'
              when /windows/i then 'https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/windows'
              when /android/i then 'https://play.google.com/store?hl=en'
              else
                root_path
              end
end
```